# Document library templates lose settings

Tags: document-library, template

I have an issue with using document library saved as templates.
When I create a new document library using the template two settings are not passed on:

1. Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents:
   it always sets: Use the server default (Open in the browser) regardless what I set in the template.
2. Content Types
   I set a certain content type to be not visible (selectable by users) in the template, when creating a new doc lib it is again visible.

Can you confirm this on your environments? Any ideas how to solve this?